# TP-Link TL-WN851ND Wireless network adapter doesn't enable sometimes

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, usb, drivers

A friend has an TP-Link TL-WN851ND Wireless network adapter. Sometimes it will work when turning on the PC, sometimes not. Then it looks like there isn't even an adapter installed.

I suspect it might be a driver problem. After installing a faulty NES Electronics USB 3.0 driver, the card suddenly disappeared.

I've removed that driver, removed the TP-Link driver as well, and reinstalled from TP-Link website. Now sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesn't..

First I'd like to know why a faulty USB 3.0 driver can impact the functionality of a PCI wireless network card?

And are there more things I can try to solve this problem once and for all?

We are using Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: The description of this problem is very vague. Have you checked whether, when you have the impression that the wifi signal disappears, it disappears also for other pcs/cell phones/...? What is the local amount of interference, i.e., are there neighbors' wifi networks on the same channel? When you experience a problem, can you say whether an ethernet connection is similarly affected?

Comment: The problem is not the wireless network itself, but the network adapter. When we can't connect it looks like there's no wireless network adapter installed, i.e. the pc can't find any networks. Upon a reboot it might work again but it becomes annoying to reboot several times before you get an Internet connection